# Converting TypeScript definition files to Kotlin

Tags: typescript, kotlin

Is it currently possible to convert `d.ts` files to Kotlin? I've found a [post which mentions that Kotlin devs are working on a converter](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5529479#5529479), but I'm not sure if the project was dropped or is it available in some kind of beta state. [This project](https://github.com/bashor/ts2kt) (apart from being undocumented) seems to use an outdated compiler, uses KotlinJS features (?) and feels like a little bit more complicated than a simple converter that consumes a file and outputs another.

Comment: As far as I know, KotlinJS (kotlin -> js compiler) was delayed in favor of a stable release of Kotlin language itself. That can be a good indicator that an typescript -> koltin compiler is not planned to the next steps.

Comment: @marcospereira Well, KotlinJS already works. Kinda. You can compile Kotlin files to JavaScript - and I'll take Kotlin over JS without hesitation (especially since you can easily share sources with the server). I think you meant they delayed *polishing* of the compiler and/or new features/libraries that they planned for KotlinJS.

Comment: yes, that was what I meant. A stable/final/polished release of KotlinJS was delayed in favor of a stable/final/polished release of Kotlin itself. ;-)

Comment: @marcospereira Still, I wanted to make sure before writing a converter myself. I'm pretty sure it will take less time to write such converter myself than struggle with the `dynamic`/`@native` syntax or convert libraries manually. (Note: I might regret that decision.)

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie, feel free to ask me any question about convertor or kotlin.js. And probably kotlinlang.slack.com is more right/convenient place for discuss about all that.

Comment: @bashor, just a quick question - could you post a simple `README.md` file on GitHub with some instructions how to run it? Judging from the `testData`, the converter is doing pretty all right - you just have to convert all the `natives` to annotations, but it's not something a simple replace-all wouldn't fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The project that you've linked to is the best thing currently available. We plan to resume work on the converter and bring it to production quality (with support, documentation etc.) after Kotlin 1.0 is released.